# Does battery voltage directly correspond to its level/percentage?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, battery, batterylevel

I found out that if you use getIntExtra("voltage", -1) in a broadcast receiver listening for ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED. It gives you the mV. I have two questions actually.

1. Does anyone know of a way I can grab the voltage at any point in time without relying on the most recent update from my broadcast receiver?

2. Does anyone know if this value is reliable enough to use for measuring battery consumption over a time interval?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer question 2 and the question in your title - most mobile devices use Lithium ion batteries and the raw voltage of the battery has a very non-linear relationship with how much capacity it has left (i.e. % charged / discharged).

Take a look at the [graph here](http://www.allaboutsymbian.com/reviews/item/15356_PhoNetInfo__.php) showing a Li-ion cell voltage against capacity left.  You can see that voltage remains roughly constant (slight downward trend) from battery full to battery about 10% capacity and then sharply falls off.

@ChrisStratton points out in a comment that the graph is not for a modern device and says that they are substantially different and may be easier to infer state of charge from voltage.  Unfortunately I could not find a link to similar graphs for a modern mobile phone battery.  However, it can be seen that modelling state of charge from open circuit voltage (OCV-SOC) remains an [active academic research](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0306261913005746) topic.

The point still stands that using the voltage to estimate state of charge is non-trivial.

Comment: This answer actually defeats the purpose of asking for an answer to the first question. so I'm going to accept your answer and call it here

Comment: While it is true that the relationship between voltage and remaining charge is non-trivial, the linked graph does not even remotely match the type of cells used in modern phones, whose discharge is substantially easier to interpret.

Comment: Yep - fair enough - Li-ion technology moves on reasonably fast.  I think the point still stands, though.  I selected the graph because it made the effect obvious.  It's surprisingly hard to find similar graphs specifically tied to a modern battery of mobile phone type (you can get cylindrical cell ones) - maybe there are commercial sensitivities in publishing.  I'll edit the answer to reflect your comment.  Maybe you can suggest a link / post an answer to a modern discharge characteristic curve if you're aware of one.

Answer (score 0):

Android manufactures are responsible for implementing on their Android version, ROM the battery discharge model for the battery they are using, which will be later used by the Android SDK see [here](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html).
You can also use

```
$ adb shell dumpsys batterystats
```

1 - I think the broadcast is the only way to get it. Some people refer that you cand read the file at /sys/class/power_supply/battery/batt_current but not all android phones have it.

2 - Based only on the voltage it's hard to calculate the battery consumption it's not a linear relationship, and different from battery to battery.